# PHP 5.x strtotime not parsing UK format d-m-y properly

Tags: php, mysql, date, strtotime, date-formatting

I've been using the same code for 5+ years, PHP 5.x and suddenly am having problems with strtotime and UK date formats.  I wrote this little script to test:

```
<?php
echo "<br /><b>PostDate: 1-7-15</b>";
$format="d-m-y";
$date="1-7-15";
$c = strtotime($date);
echo "<br /><b>Unix TS: - ".$c."</b>";
$a = date($format,$c) ;
echo "<br /><b>Unix TS to date - ".$a."</b>";
echo "<br /> <br />";
echo "<br /><b>PostDate: 7/1/15</b>";
$format="m/d/y";
$date="7/1/15";
$c = strtotime($date);
echo "<br /><b>Unix TS: - ".$c."</b>";
$a = date($format,$c) ;
echo "<br /><b>Unix TS to date - ".$a."</b>";
?>
```

This outputs:

```
PostDate: 1-7-15
Unix TS: - 995173200
Unix TS to date - 15-07-01


PostDate: 7/1/15
Unix TS: - 1435726800
Unix TS to date - 07/01/15
```

You can plainly see that the UK version is not correct, the US version is is correct.  The UK version is not converting to Unix Time stamp correctly.

Like I said before, I've been using strtotime this way for years, suddenly these results?  Am I losing my mind?

Comment: have you tested other php versions

Comment: I've tried 5.4, 5.5, 5.6 and 7.0.  7.0 blew my code immediately so I ran for cover.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  Got it for next time.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the line:

```
$c = strtotime($date);
```

To:

```
$c=strtotime(date($format, strtotime($date)));
```

and it works for all date formats, even d M y.  So strange...